# UIView to cover TabbarController : Human Interface Guideline

Tags: ios, iphone, uitabbarcontroller, human-interface

I have an `UIViewController` level information that i want to show to the user (This information is an important information that user should notice in my app). I also have a `TabbarController` which has some other `UIViewControllers` in other tabs. I am thinking to show a `UIView` that will cover the whole screen even the `TabbarController` to show this important information for few seconds.

Keeping this thing in view that this is a one `UIViewController` level information, My question is that is it a good ides to cover the whole screen even the TabBarController for few seconds. Does Human Interface Design prohibits it  or its allowed?

Comment: Isn't what you're trying to do basicly a `UIViewController` presented with a `modal segue`?

Answer (score 0):

Shortly, yes you can do what you are saying. HIU is ok with that. Good Luck!